# Two jQuery functions not working together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that fits the text into a div no matter its length ...

```
function fitin() {
$('#fitin div').css('font-size', '1em');

while ($('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height()) {
  $('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size')) - 1) + "px");
}

}
```

And it works for what is originally written in the html, but when I use a function to replace the text

```
function getVerse() {

var verses = ["this is one", "this is two"];
var index = 0;
var verse = "";
$("#button2").click(function() {

  $.getJSON("http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&formatting=plain&type=json&callback=?", function(data) {
    verse = JSON.stringify(data[0].text);
      //alert(verse);
  });
  if (index >= verses.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  $("#fitin").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $(this).html("<b>" + verse + "test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test" + "</b>").fadeIn(500);
    fitin();
    index++;
  });
});

}
```

fitin() doesn't work. Here is a link to the [codepen here](http://codepen.io/mwilkes1222/pen/evKRNp?editors=1010).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
(parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size'))
```

The result of `$('#fitin div').css('font-size'))` is a string like `50px` and it can not parse to int. To solve the problem do this:

```
$('#fitin div').css('font-size', (parseInt($('#fitin div').css('font-size').replace("px", "")) - 1) + "px");
```

If the string is a number with 'em' (2em) change to `replace("em", "")`

Comment: There should be `+"px"` at the end of the line which changes the number to px.

Comment: After you did `parseInt` and add value then add the pixel.

Comment: I put the total line of code. And you have another problem that is mentioned in others answer. @Dhiraj answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working pen](http://codepen.io/alsiola/pen/gmjEpo?editors=1010).  You had a couple of problems.

Firstly, when you updated the text in the verse you were not replacing the `<div>` around it, so the selector `$('#fitin div')` in `fitin()` was no longer selecting anything.  Changed

```
$(this).html("<b>" + verse + "test ..." + "</b>").fadeIn(500);
```

to:

```
$(this).html("<div><b>" + verse + "test ..." + "</b></div>").fadeIn(500);
```

Secondly, although the `.html()` function is synchronous, the browser redraw takes a non-zero amount of time to happen.  Until the redraw happens, your `fitin()` function won't work.  A little bit hacky, but this is solved by changing;

```
fitin();
```

To:

```
setTimeout(fitin, 0);
```

Thirdly, your font-size changing code was not going to work properly because it relied on parsing integers out of strings with non-numeric characters, so I modified that a little to make it work:

```
function fitin() {
    var initialSize = 16;
    do {
      $('#fitin div').css('font-size', initialSize + "px");
    } while (($('#fitin div').height() > $('#fitin').height()) && --initialSize)
}
```